# Accessing indent length with enumitem

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumitem, lengths

For a package I'm writing, I need to access the actual amount a list item is indented.  Here's a minimal example showing what lengths are available to me, but they don't seem to give me what I need. For example, I need to be able to know the length from the left margin of the page to the 'An' in item *(1)* and the 'A' in item *a.*

The helper macro shows some of the relevant lengths, but the values for `\leftmargin` clearly aren't absolute. How can I calculate that length?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand\showlengths{\the\leftmargin;\the\labelwidth;\the\labelindent;\the\labelsep}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item An item \showlengths
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item A subitem \showlengths
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: `\@totalleftmargin`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that does exactly what I want. I had no idea such a length existed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the length `\@totalleftmargin` is exactly the length needed. Here's a demonstration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\showlengths{\the\@totalleftmargin}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\arabic*)]
\item An item \showlengths


\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*.]
\item A subitem \showlengths


\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\rule{25pt}{1pt}

\rule{47pt}{1pt}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: So the left margin of any indented item is only measured from the `leftmargin` of the preceding item. Interesting insight :)